# I am getting error System.HttpResponse[Status=Server Error, StatusCode=500] for the following code

Tags: apex, callout

I am runing my code from anonymous window

```
HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
Http http=new Http();
//Header
req.setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml');
req.setHeader('SOAPAction','');
//Body
String reqbody='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'+'<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns'+':xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns'+':env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
+'<env:Body>'
+'<n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">'
+'<n1:username>[REDACTED]</n1:username>'
+'<n1:password>[REDACTED]</n1:password>'
+'</n1:login>'+' </env:Body>'
+'</env:Envelope>';
system.debug(reqbody);
req.setbody(reqbody);
//Method
req.setMethod('POST');
//Endpoint
req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/44.0');
//Request Sent
HttpResponse res=http.send(req);

System.debug(res);
```

Comment: I've removed what appeared to be production credentials in the screenshot you posted and in the body of your question. Please consider changing those credentials **immediately**, as they're accessible to the open Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is in the header

We need to use `req.setHeader('SOAPAction','""');`
instead of `req.setHeader('SOAPAction','');`